# How to save a meta_value as a numeric value after I retrieve it via update_post_meta?

Tags: post-meta, meta-value

I tried things like $meta_rwp_user_score = (number_format_i18n($meta_rwp_user_score, 2)); , but this is not working. Where do I use that?

```
<?php
$meta_rwp_user_score['meta_rwp_user_score'] = get_post_meta(($anbieter_id),'rwp_user_score',true);

foreach ( $meta_rwp_user_score as $key => $value ) :
  if ( 'revision' === $post->post_type ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( get_post_meta( $postid, $key, false ) ) {
    // If the custom field already has a value, update it.
    update_post_meta( $postid, $key, $value );
  } else {
    // If the custom field doesn't have a value, add it.
    add_post_meta( $postid, $key, $value);
  }

  if ( ! $value ) {
    // Delete the meta key if there's no value
    delete_post_meta( $postid, $key );
  }

endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: If you go to database using such as phpmyadmin, you will find that the post_meta meta_value is set as `longtext`. I believe it is because meta_value is served as a generic purpose for all situation. You will need to handle it by case when retrieving it.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. What would you prefer to do now? I'm still on a beginner level of programming.

Comment: I have added an example on converting it to float number before you use it. So it might help. See if it is what you are looking for. Sorry that last week was swamped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the database schema, the `meta_value` is stored as `longtext`. It is probably because of generic purpose. So, to obtain a numeric value. There are 2 parts for doing so.

#### Saving

Although it is storing as longtext, it is still good for preparing the rightful numeric format so that when retrieve it, it is likely to be expected value for conversion.
So, for checking before saving, may use [is_float()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) or [is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and so on to make sure the storing value is expected.

#### Retrieving

If the type float number is required to manipulate it correctly in the code after fetching the meta value from database. You may consider using php built-in function [floatval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) for float number to convert it before using. Another one is [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) for integer.

```
$meta_rwp_user_score['meta_rwp_user_score'] = floatval( get_post_meta(($anbieter_id),'rwp_user_score',true) );

// any text will be converted to 0

// manipulate as needed
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think, I got it now with that function. Wish you all the best for the future!

Comment: You are welcome. If it resolve yoir problem, would you mind just accepting the answer to make it completed? At least it future visitor would know it is resolved in a rightful way. And thanks again for your positive feedback. Forgot to welcome you to WPSE! Happy coding and learning!